# java code to resolve SSLHandShakeException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying to connect https URL and read/download the content from that URL using Java code. Initially i was facing unauthorised exception **403** but then i have used `proxy settings` to overcome this scenario. I have resolved the 403 exceptions, but facing the below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

Please advice how to solve SSLHandShakeException using Java code.

Comment: Your details are not enough. What is the URL you are trying to access? This may be caused by certificate issues.

Comment: I am trying to access Jenkins URL. Can I disable the certificates using java code for testing purpose?

Comment: Grammatical corrections are made and unnecessary parts are removed.

Comment: You can start your app with "-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake" to see the handshake information, however "Remote host closed connection" indicates the connection has been simply closed by the other party

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
```

in source before any network call or run server with following arguments

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```